# How to select records by int identity as starting with n given numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search records by its `BIGINT` primary key (SQL Server identity), but a want to compare them as string, not as numbers. I need it to suggest data in GUI of application.

Is it possible to find record by this way, while primary key index will still be used? How?

Select should on `'123'` query select rows like:

```
123
123456
123654654
```

Comment: Use the wild card: fieldName like '123%' ... also do at least post what you tried sql/code wise

Comment: The answers given allow you to the functionallity you are asking for. They will ***not***, however, use the primary key to index the searching. Mostly because the PK is ***not*** in the same order as it would be were the field a string. For example; `1` is next to `2` numerically, but `'1'` is next to `'11'` alphanumerically. If it is important to use an index, create a new field where this value is a string, and then index that new field.

Comment: Thank you Dems. I would like to mark your answer as accepted, but I can't...

Comment: I really do not understand why somebody marks my question not useful. I can understand it only in situation if these guys doesn't red carefully "using index" part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`LEFT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) function for that:

```
WHERE LEFT(col1 ,3) = 123;
```

[See this Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/82620)

> Is it possible to find record by this way, **while primary key index will still be used? How?**

As @Dems explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930934/how-to-select-records-by-int-identity-as-starting-with-n-given-numbers/12931636#comment17525117_12931636), you can not make use of an index on the original datatype when you cast it in `VARCHAR`.

Comment: You may not be typing `CAST` but there is an ***implicit*** CAST in there. Look at the execution plan to check. This behaves just the same as `LEFT(CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(10)), 3)`

Comment: @Dems Ahh. Correct. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: No. The datatype is different from the data-type the Op is trying to use. One can only perform string operations on strings. A BIGINT is stored and sorted in a totally different manner compared to a VARCHAR. Your answers functionally work, they're as good as the OP will get.  The OP ***can not*** avoid the `CAST()` and ***can not*** make use of an index on the original datatype.

Comment: Because I can't select Dems answer, I am choosing yours. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to [`CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) your column in `VARCHAR` (while selecting data) to search like `123%`

```
WHERE CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE '123%'
```

[See this Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/82625)

> Is it possible to find record by this way, **while primary key index will still be used? How?**

As @Dems explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930934/how-to-select-records-by-int-identity-as-starting-with-n-given-numbers/12931636#comment17525117_12931636), you can not make use of an index on the original datatype when you cast it in `VARCHAR`.

Comment: `...AS VARCHAR(MAX)` seems a bit overkill, considerung an `INT` value can never really have more than 10-15 digits.....

Comment: From the OP: `while primary key index will still be used? How?`

Comment: @Dems If we don't want to cast we can use `LEFT` function as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12931636/1369235).

Comment: @hims056 - It still won't matter.  `a.` There is still a CAST, it's just hidden as an implicit cast.  `b.` It still won't use any existing index.

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not use % wildcard like the following:

```
where id like '123%'
```

Comment: because `id` is a **numerical** column (type `bigint`) and numerical columns cannot be search with `LIKE '123%'`....